# Placing a message onto RabbitMQ from service broker

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, service-broker

We have the scenario where by we want to display real time front end updates using signal-R based on SQL database changes (These changed come from array of systems).
We initially went down the route of SQLDependancy + service broker,  however,

1. It didnt provide the undated info
2. The SQL statement used contained an array of inner joins, which started to impact performance when used with SQLDependancy

We also looked at SQLDependancy and monitoring the service broker queue, but again, there was a performance issue with this.

The option that we are looking at, is to use RabbitMQ. ie. Service broker to place a message onto RabbitMQ.

Is this possible? we are struggle to find any acceptable samples for this?